# onfocus not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am putting together some javascript form validation and i cant figure out how to get this onfocus to take hold of my div... i just need it to alert me that my onfocus function is making contact with my last name imput... :(

html:

```
<div id="contact">
    <form name="form1" action="send.php" method="post" id="contact_f">
      <table id="contact_table">
        <tr>
          <td class="col1" colspan="2">
            <h1 class="center_text">Contact Aron</h1>
            <div id="error_messages">
              errors
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col1">
            <label for="first_name">First Name*</label><br>
            <input id="first_name" required name="Name" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
          </td>
          <td class="col2">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name*</label><br>
            <input id="last_name" required type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col1">
            <label for="email">Email*</label><br>
            <input id="email" required type="email">
          </td>
          <td class="col2">
            <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Email*</label><br>
            <input id="confirm_email" required type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col1">
            <label for="phone">Phone Number   <span id="color_gray">xxx-xxx-xxxx</span></label><br>
            <input id="phone" type="tel" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}">
          </td>
          <td class="col2">

          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="col2">
          <td class="col1" colspan="2">
            <label for="message">Message*</label><br>
            <textarea id="message" required type="text"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col1" colspan="2">
            <button id="submit_button" type="submit" value="submit">Submit Form</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
```

javascript in question:

```
    document.getElementById("last_name").onfocus=function() {
      alert("last name");
    };
```

Comment: I tested your code, `its running WELL!!!!`

Comment: @Rajesh The element is an `input` element; the duplicate target is not relevant. Your DOM is probably not loaded at that time. Does the console print any errors? Where exactly is the script?

Comment: @Xufox "i cant figure out how to get this onfocus to take hold of my div..." this explains different story?

Comment: Then probably it was my misunderstanding. My apologies.

Comment: The input is for my website contact form alilland.com what I posted above is the code for the form field, surprisingly I can't get any reaction from the JavaScript that should work fine Iv gone from id to id trying to get any indication at all that my JavaScript is grabbing hold of the form element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code is working fine. You can try it with using jquery, like this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#last_name" ).focus(function() {
alert("Last name");
});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
document.getElementById("last_name").onfocus=function() {
   alert(this.value);
};
```

Comment: I'm not trying per say to alert what I input I'm just trying to get any indication at all that my on focus event is touching the input field

Comment: @AronLilland: you should bind the event to div and then check whether target is input or not. are you fine with jquery solution.

Comment: @AronLilland You still haven’t answered my questions: _“Your DOM is probably not loaded at that time. Does the console print any errors? Where exactly is the script?”_

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 window.addEventListener('load',function(){

document.getElementById("last_name").addEventListener('focus',function() {
       alert(this.value);
    });

 });
```